# Transforming Riemann Sum into Integral Form

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

I am a bit struggling with transforming a Riemann's sum into its *definite integral form*.

I am given the following equation:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\left(3-\frac{i}{n}\right)^3\right) \frac{1}{n}
$$

Now, so far I have understood that to transform a Riemann sum we need to use the following rule:

$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n f(a+i \Delta x) \Delta x=\int_a^b f(x) d x
$$
From this, we can equate matching parts of both equations:

1. $a$ from $a+i \Delta x = 3-\frac{i}{n}$, which means that $a=3$;
2. $b$ from $\Delta x=\frac{1}{n}$, and since $\Delta x$ is also equal to $\frac{b-a}{n}$, $b-a=1$, therefore $b=4$.
3. $f(x)$, which is where a have the **problem**, (assuming I've done the rest correctly).

Since I don't have an explicit function here like say $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n ln(2+\frac{5i}{n})$, where we can immediately see that $f(x)$ is $ln(x)$, I thought that in my case the function is probably the power inside the parenthesis, or $x^3$. Is that correct, or am I wrong here?

Using this, I got $\int_3^4 x^3 d x$, which is $\frac{175}{4}=43.75$, which is different from the converging value of the Riemann sum when $n=1000$, which is around $16.24$, so I must be wrong somewhere.

Comment: When you "matched the parts of the equations" you ignored the minus sign in $3 - (i/n)$. Try thinking about the meaning of the sum as an approximation to some area instead of reasoning with the shape of the expression.